# Creating ExtJS tree dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to create a simple tree with two parent nodes using ExtJS. The root node will be invisible. The tree should look like:

+Invisible
|
|_A
|_B
+Visible
|
|_C
|_D

My query from the database is returning result in the following format

Description | IsVisible
A                  0
B                  0
C                  1
D                  1

I have seen examples online, for example(http://www.clintharris.net/2011/how-to-use-extjs-4-treepanels-with-both-static-data-and-model-stores/) but they all show creating tree dynamically with only one parent node whereas I need to create it for two parent nodes. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Comment: Can you post your response from the server?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the structure of the response that you are getting from the server.It will be easy to answer if u post ur server response ...